# Unity 5 multiplayer networking

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been looking for a unity 5 socket client to add to a socket based game I am testing out. I already have a socket.io server running but need a client side solution now, is there a client special client that unity will use and how can I get it set up?

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721 try this

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I did take a look on it but saw a comment saying deprecated. @CổChíTâm